# How to show / hide ImageView in FrameLayout

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-framelayout

Im trying to show / hide a specifically `ImageView`, that it's inside a `FrameLayout`. At the same time, im gonna hide or show (on the contrary to `ImageView`), the `LinearLayout` with id **recents_linear_layout**

```
<com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/recents_root"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/recents_bg_protect"
    android:background="@drawable/status_bar_recents_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsHorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/recents_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/status_bar_recents_right_glow_margin"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/status_bar_recents_fading_edge_length"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/recents_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false">
        </LinearLayout>


    </com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsHorizontalScrollView>

**<ImageView android:id="@+id/landscape"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0.0dip"
    android:src="@drawable/landscape_img"
    android:visibility="gone" />**

</FrameLayout>

<include layout="@layout/status_bar_no_recent_apps"
    android:id="@+id/recents_no_apps"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsPanelView>
```

My java code, throws a `NullPointerException`, because it cant find the `ImageView` (because this is being executed on `com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsHorizontalScrollView`. This is the code

```
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.recents_linear_layout);
    mLinearLayout.setVisibility(mRecent ? LinearLayout.GONE : LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
mLandScape = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.landscape);
mLandScape.setVisibility(mRecent ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ImageView is outside the scope of your RecentsHorizontalScrollView  you'd have to pass it in somehow

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. But I have no Idea how to retrieve the ID, for using the findViewById Method

EDIT: Seems like I fixed it, edited main post

Comment: Yep you moved it into scope. You shouldn't really edit it, just answer your own question below instead.

Comment: I will answer but I need 8 hours because of reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

you could use ((Activity)getContext()).findViewById(R.id.landscape) though you should avoid it since there is no guarantee that the context is an activity. I can't understand why you are trying to hide some views inside this view. I think this is the activity's responsibility. You should make some interface with call back method to notify the activity about your event then let it hide the image view.

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED**
Fix was making a external layout container with old Layout and ImageView as childs

```
    <com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsHorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/recents_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/status_bar_recents_right_glow_margin"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/status_bar_recents_fading_edge_length"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:clipChildren="false">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/child_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:clipChildren="false">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/recents_linear_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:clipChildren="false" />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/sense_landscape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/sense_landscape"
        android:visibility="visible" />



        </LinearLayout>


    </com.android.systemui.recent.RecentsHorizontalScrollView>
```